# triangle relation equation of a pentagon

Tags: geometry

ABCDE is an irregular-shaped pentagon. No angle is more than 180.
prove that, 
           area of (ABD)*(AEC)-area of (ABC)*(ADE) = area of (ABE)*(ACD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use coordinate geometry to solve this problem.  Let side AE lie on the x-axis and point A is $(0,0)$, B is $(x_1, y_1)$, C is $(x_2, y_2)$, D is $(x_3, y_3)$, E is $(x_4, 0)$.

In coordinate geometry we have a way to find the area of any polygon using its vertices.

Area ABD is $\frac{1}{2}(x_1y_3 - x_3y_1)$

Area AEC is $\frac{1}{2}(x_4y_2)$

Area ABC is $\frac{1}{2}(x_1y_2 - x_2y_1)$

Area ADE is $\frac{1}{2}(x_4y_3)$

Area ABE is $\frac{1}{2}(x_4y_1)$

Area ACD is $\frac{1}{2}(x_2y_3 - x_3y_2)$

Hence Area ABD x Area AEC - Area ABC x Area ADE is

$\frac{1}{4}(x_2x_4y_1y_3 - x_3x_4y_1y_2)$

For the right hand side Area ABE x Area ACD is the same.  Hence proved.